# JPQL inner join

Tags: mysql, database, hql, jpql

I am trying to convert mysql code into JPQL. I have two tables. The first table is named Product. It has the following fields: id and code. The second table is called Descriptor which has 3 fields: id ( from product table), code ( from product table) and Description which is a field specific to the Descriptor table. I want to join the tables so for each unique combination of product id and product code I want the description added on.

```
    The Sql is as follows ( this is correct): 
    Select Product.id, Product.code, Descriptor.DESCRIPTION
    from Product Inner join Descriptor where 
    Product.id = Descriptor.id and 
    Product.code = Descriptor.code

(The error is in here)
The JPQL I am trying is as follows which results in a "path" error
select p from Product p INNER JOIN Descriptor d where 
p.id = d.id and p.code = d.code;
```

All advice very welcome thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [documentation about HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins). Joins, in HQL, are done using associations between entities:

```
select p from Product p 
inner join p.descriptor d 
where p.code = d.code;
```

(assuming there is a OneToOne association between Product and Descriptor, using their respective IDs).

Comment: I did read the documentation. It is terrible. Thanks for your feedback though. I appreciate you taking the time to answer